# Can I group UIViews into another UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview

I have a question about iOS views hierarchy (thank you for your answers).

The context : I use a switch view (2 segments) to hide or show several `UIView`s (`UILabel`s, `UISlider`s).

Is it a good practice to wrap these `UIView`s in a `UIView` wrapper to group the `setHidden:YES/NO` ?

For example I first had :

```
[label1 setHidden:YES]
[label2 setHidden:YES]
[label3 setHidden:YES]
[label4 setHidden:YES]
[picker1 setHidden:YES]
```

and I transformed it by putting the labels an the picker in one unique `UIView` (in interface builder), I connected this `UIView`

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *multipleViewsContainer;
```

and I then do one unique :

```
[multipleViewsContainer setHidden:YES]
```

I just wondered if I could use UIView like that or if there was another mean to hide/show groups of views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You can embed multiple UIViews into another UIView and then hide or show the whole thing via a "`setHidden`" call.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I just saw this yesterday, looking at someone else's code. Before I didn't know I could do it :)